# T SQL: Inner join in sub select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm a WPF developer not a sql dba... Trying to do a join in a sub select. 
I have two tables: tbArticles & tbRegions. TbArticles holds a regionCode column which is also common to tbRegions. I'm trying to get a count of all articles by region and country:

[image]

[image]

This is the result I'm looking for:

[image]

I've managed to get the countrys by region from an inner join:

```
select distinct r.longName, a.Country
from ises.tbarticles a
INNER JOIN ref.tbRegions r
On a.RegionCode = r.regionCode
order by longName
```

But how do I get the result I want with the join as a sub select? I've tried this sort of thing but obviously it's not right.

```
select (select distinct r.longName from ises.tbarticles a
INNER JOIN ref.tbRegions r
on r.regionCode = a.RegionCode) as 'Region', country, COUNT(*) as 'Total Articles' from ises.tbarticles a, ref.tbRegions r
group by country
order by Region
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select r.longName, a.Country, count(*)
from ises.tbarticles a
INNER JOIN ref.tbRegions r
On a.RegionCode = r.regionCode
group by  r.longName, a.Country
order by longName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use need to use [GROUP BY Clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) and then the count

```
Select r.longName, a.Country, Count(a.*) as ArticleCount
From ises.tbarticles a 
     INNER JOIN ref.tbRegions r On a.RegionCode = r.regionCode
Group By r.longName, a.Country
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @TbArticles TABLE(regionCode INT, Coutry NVARCHAR(MAX), Body NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @TbRegions TABLE(regionCode INT, Name NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @TbArticles VALUES
(10, N'Australia', 'blah'),
(10, N'Fiji', 'blah'),
(12, N'USA', 'blah'),
(15, N'Belgium', 'blah')


INSERT INTO @TbRegions VALUES
(10, N'Australia'),
(12, N'North America'),
(15, N'Western Europe')



SELECT r.Name, a.Coutry, COUNT(*) AS ArticleCount FROM @TbArticles a
JOIN @TbRegions r ON r.regionCode = a.regionCode
GROUP BY r.regionCode, r.Name, a.Coutry
```

Output:

```
Name            Coutry      ArticleCount
Australia       Australia   1
Australia       Fiji        1
North America   USA         1
Western Europe  Belgium     1
```